# Disable automatic punctuation from Microsoft Azure Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I'm using Azure STT service, and My goal is to disable the automatic punctuation from recognized results.

I'm using continuous recognition from continuous streaming source with following code:

```
// Initialize the Stream Handling PullAudioInputStreamCallback derived class            
var audioStream = new VoiceAudioStream();

// Initialize with the format required by the Speech service
var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(8000, 16, 1);

// Configure speech SDK to work with the audio stream in right format. 
var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioStream, audioFormat);

// Get credentials and region from client's message.
var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region);
speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "it-IT";
speechConfig.EnableDictation(); //<- Dictation Mode

// With all the info at hand, finally create the SpeechRecognizer instance.
var speechClient = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
// Finally start.                 

await speechClient.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
```

Here is the class derived from `PullAudioInputStreamCallback` that I'm using:

```
public class VoiceAudioStream : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
{
    private readonly EchoStream _dataStream = new();
    private ManualResetEvent _waitForEmptyDataStream = null;

    public override int Read(byte[] dataBuffer, uint size)
    {
        if (_waitForEmptyDataStream != null && !_dataStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            _waitForEmptyDataStream.Set();
            return 0;
        }

        return _dataStream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _dataStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        if (_dataStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            _waitForEmptyDataStream = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _waitForEmptyDataStream.WaitOne();
        }

        _waitForEmptyDataStream.Close();
        _dataStream.Dispose();
        base.Close();
    }
}
```

Here the code of EchoStream Class:

```
public class EchoStream : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _DataReady = new(false);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _Buffers = new();

    public bool DataAvailable { get { return !_Buffers.IsEmpty; } }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _Buffers.Enqueue(buffer.Take(count).ToArray()); // add new data to buffer
        _DataReady.Set(); // allow waiting reader to proceed
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _DataReady.WaitOne(); // block until there's something new to read

        if (!_Buffers.TryDequeue(out byte[] lBuffer)) // try to read
        {
            _DataReady.Reset();
            return -1;
        }

        if (!DataAvailable)
            _DataReady.Reset();

        Array.Copy(lBuffer, buffer, lBuffer.Length);
        return lBuffer.Length;
    }
}
```

Recognizing works fine except automatic punctuation, that still works despite being enabled "Dictation".

So some suggestion how to disable automatic punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the problem that was in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech package version 1.34.0.

Updating to the new release 1.34.1 "Dictation Mode" Works as well.

Thank you to all body.

Piercarlo